# Python, mpg123 and subprocess not properly using stdin.write or communicate

Tags: python, subprocess

ok, so my google-fu really kind of sucks and I was unable to find an answer, hopefully you folks can help me ^_^

ok, so what I thought would be a simple script is seemingly not communicating with its subprocess correctly, I'm running this line by line. I'm also using the mpg123 player, this is a Linux system (well, Raspberry Pi)

```
    from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
    p = Popen(["mpg123", "-C", "test.mp3"], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
    #wait a few seconds to enter this, "q" without a newline is how the controls for the player work to quit out if it were ran like "mpg123 -C test.mp3" on the command line
    p.communicate(input='q')[0]
```

I can run stdout.read() on it just fine, but using communicate for input just makes it hang and p.stdin.write('q') does seemingly nothing at all. This is python related though I have a feeling I'm also not looking in the right place in the mpg123 documentation. Please be kind as I'm exceptionally new to this ^_^

Comment: I'm not familiar with mpg123, but `communicate()` blocks until the process terminates.  Is this what you expect?

Comment: actually I'm just looking for a way to use subprocess to stop playback of mpg123 lol, I fear asking here is bad because it's relating to mpg123 as well. Passing "q" into mpg123 as this stage should quit out of the program, so if communicate is blocking until the process terminates should be fine because the program should exit anyway

Comment: It looks like mpg123 is having issues accepting the 'q' because it's trying to hard too detect the terminal type.  Does replacing the `p.communicate(...)` call with `p.kill(); p.stdout.read()` meet your needs?

Comment: that will work quite nicely, much appreciated =) Though your answer has me curious, "it's trying to hard too detect the terminal type" what does this mean? (preferably in an "Idiot's guide to..." format hehe) and how did you determine that?

Comment: I used the `p.kill(); p.stdout.read()` approach and noticed the line "Can't get terminal attributes", which isn't there when I just ran the same command directly from the command line.  Googling the error shows [some version of the source](http://musikcube.googlecode.com/svn-history/r314/trunk/src/contrib/mpg123decoder/mpg123/src/term.c), which looks like if it fails to detect the terminal, it doesn't enable it.

Comment: oh, C(++), haven't gotten that far yet lol, however; that's so cool!

Comment: Have you solved this? I have the same issue

Answer (score 0):

Check what arguments your `mpg123` version understands. The following works on my machine:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import time
from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, DEVNULL, STDOUT

p = Popen(["mpg123", "-K", "test.mp3"], stdin=PIPE, stdout=DEVNULL, stderr=STDOUT)

# wait a little
time.sleep(3)

# send command "Skip song", wait for the player to exit
p.communicate(b'n')[0]
```

It starts playing the file, waits ~3 seconds, and exits.

Answer (score 0):

This is an awful solution, but it works in a pinch. I'm using this as a patch because for some reason, I cannot get Python libraries to play properly on my Raspberry Pi.

If you start `mpg123` in remote mode (`mpg123 -R`), you can send commands to it far more easily:

```
proc = sp.Popen(["mpg123", "-R"], stdin=sp.PIPE)
```

Then, you can send commands to its `stdin` attribute.

Note:

- The commands are different. To pause, it's `"pause"`, not `" "` for example. Run `mpg123 -R` in a console, then send it the `help` command to see a list of commands.
- The commands need to be newline terminated.

---

From the docs:

> -R, --remote
>
> Activate generic control interface. mpg123 will then read and execute commands from stdin. Basic usage is ''load  '' to play some file and the obvious ''pause'', ''command. ''jump '' will jump/seek to a given point (MPEG frame number). Issue ''help'' to get a full list of commands and syntax.