# python 2.7 - subprocess control interaction with mpg123

Tags: python, subprocess, pty

I asked a question related to this several weeks ago on here:
[Python, mpg123 and subprocess not properly using stdin.write or communicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17159627/python-mpg123-and-subprocess-not-properly-using-stdin-write-or-communicate)

Thanks to help from there I was able to do what I needed at the time. (Didn't call q, but terminated the subprocess to stop it).## Heading ##
Now though I seem to be in another bit of a mess.

```
    from subprocess import Popen, PIPE, STDOUT
    p = Popen(["mpg123", "-C", "test.mp3"], stdout=PIPE, stdin=PIPE, stderr=STDOUT)
    #wait a few seconds to enter this, "q" without a newline is how the controls for the player work to quit out if it were ran like "mpg123 -C test.mp3" on the command line
    p.communicate(input='q')[0]
```

much like before, I need this to be able to quit out of mpg123 like it would be with it's standard controls (like press 'q' to quit, or '-' to turn volume down, '+' to turn volume up, etc), now I use the code above, which should theoretically work, and it works with similar programs. Does anyone know of a way I can use the controls built into mpg123 (the one accessible by using "mpg123 -C whatever.mp3") using a subprocess? terminate isn't enough anymore as I will need the controls ^_^

EDIT: Many thanks to abarnert for the amazing answer =)
ok, so the new code is simply a slightly modified version of abarnert's answer, however mpg123 doesn't seem to be accepting the commands

```
    import os
    import pty
    import sys
    import time

    pid, fd = os.forkpty()
    if pid:
        time.sleep(5)
        os.write(fd, 'b') #this should've restarted the file
        time.sleep(5)
        os.write(fd, 'q') #unfortunately doesn't quit here =(
        time.sleep(5) # quits after this is finished executing
    else:
        os.spawnl(os.P_WAIT, '/usr/bin/mpg123', '-C', 'TEST file.mp3')
```

Comment: Is there a reason you want to try to control the `mpg123` player instead of, say, using a Python library (or even bindings for `libmpg123`) to play the music and do your own controls?

Comment: mainly because I'm a newbie lol, most things I'm seeing for playback with the Raspberry Pi (my particular platform) uses mpg123 or mpg321, it was suggested to me when I said I'd like to be able to play mp3's through python to use a subprocess with one of those players

Comment: First, sorry for my excessive abbreviation; it seems to have led you astray. Whenever I'm dealing with POSIX-style code I revert to using words like `pid` and `fd` as if everyone should understand what they mean. A `pid` is a Process ID, not a Parent ID—and in this case, it's the _child_ process ID, so calling it `parentID` is confusing. And an `fd` is a File Descriptor (or, for really old people File Descriptor index), not a File Dir.

Comment: Meanwhile, calling `queue.get(False)` in a `while True:` loop is a bad idea, especially if you don't have anything to do while waiting. Basically, until something comes in, you're using up as much CPU as possible to keep asking "are we there yet?". Just use `queue.get(True)` and/or pass a timeout.

Comment: Finally… I'm not actually sure what happens when you use `forkpty` (or just `fork`) from a `multiprocessing.Process`. Are you sure it works with the `q` and not the `b`? Is it possible that it just works N% of the time at random, or every time after the first, etc.?

Comment: yea I actually read that it was a processID and file descriptor in the  documentation but didn't change it in my code, apologies. the voiceStop currently works though, many tests and the behavior is consistent

Comment: ahh, ok, I'm going to re-edit my original post as a much more stripped down version doesn't actually seem to be accepting anything but rather simply ends when the script does (after the time.sleep)

Comment: If you want to mix `multiprocessing` with `os.forkpty` you may need to close the socket-or-pipe descriptors that `multiprocessing.Pipe` creates.  Seems like a bug of sorts that `multiprocessing` doesn't set the close-on-exec flag.

Comment: @torek unfortunately the problem still exists with multiprocessing taken out =( I've re-edited the original post to reflect the problem more accurately =)

Comment: @torek: But that shouldn't be a problem as long as you do the `forkptr` within the child process, right? In other words, shouldn't `openpty` either work properly, or fail noisily (at least on linux and modern *BSD)?

Comment: @newbToPython: That's because of a really stupid bug in my code: With `spawnl`, you have to pass the program name, then a *complete* `argv`—as in, including `argv[0]`. As written, mpg123 ends up seeing `-C` as its name, rather than one of its arguments, so it doesn't enable control keys… See my edited answer, or just repeat `'/usr/bin/mp3'` in the list of parameters to `spawnl`.

Comment: @newbToPython: This is, of course, exactly why I always tell everyone else to copy and paste the exact same code they run to SO. Because otherwise, you are guaranteed to do stupid things like this. Or at least I am… :)

Comment: @abarnert: I'm not worried about the pty opening part, just about multiprocessing "getting stuck" waiting for the EOF on a pipe/socket that it won't get because the child process has the fd open.  Cheap-and-cheerful hack around the problem is to close all "unwanted" fd's in the child (`subprocess` does this if `close_fds` is `True`)...

Comment: @torek: Maybe I'm just not understanding this. I can see how there would be a problem if the _parent_ process called `openpty`. I can see how there might be a problem if the child tried to attach the grandchild's terminal to its own stdio ala `pty.spawn`. But a child just calling `openpty` or `forkpty` after inheriting some fd's it doesn't care about… what's the harm? They're entirely independent files.

Comment: @abarnert: parent: r, w = os.pipe(); pid = fork(); (parent: loop) read(r) (until EOF). To be extra-concrete let's say r == 7 and w == 8.  (child1) close(r); write(w); pid = fork(); (child2) exec("forever", "program that loops forever and must be sent stop cmd or kill()ed"); (child1) write(w); close(w).  Now back in parent we're reading (r) until EOF but child2, which has exec'ed and has w open, runs forever.  child1 has done a close(w) expecting that to signal EOF to parent, but "forever" has w (fd 8) open, without knowing or caring about it, doesn't close(8), parent never sees EOF!

Comment: @torek: I'm still not getting it. The issue is child2 inheriting 8 from child1, not child1 inheriting anything from parent, right? So how could `multiprocessing` help here? It can't close `w` in child1 until child1 is done with it—which it isn't, because it still plans to `write(w)` after forking off child2. And it can't help child2 at all, because child2 is launched by `forkpty`, not `multiprocessing`. So the only option is to do explicit closes between `forkpty` and `execl`. Which, as far as I know, can't be done portably with `exec`, but can with `spawn` (though it means an extra `fork`).

Comment: @abarnert: Yes.  `multiprocessing` is a bit of a red herring here, as it's a generic problem, but the multiprocessing module can "protect itself" by setting close-on-exec.  Well-behaved libraries should protect themselves as much as possible, as a general rule...

Comment: @torek: To clarify: I mean it can't be done portably if you don't have some out-of-band way of keeping track of the files to close. In your case, and in many real-life cases, you do, so that's perfectly fine, and possibly the best answer. Anyway, the point is, Python doesn't expose `O_CLOEXEC`, so you can't do things the "easy" way.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32844/discussion-between-torek-and-abarnert)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really need the controls, you can't just use `Popen`.

`mpg123` only enables terminal control if its stdin is a tty, not if it's a file or pipe. That's why you get this line in the banner:

```
Terminal control enabled, press 'h' for listing of keys and functions.
```

And the whole point of `Popen` (and `subprocess`, and the POSIX APIs it's built on) is pipes.

So, what can you do about it?

---

On linux, you can use the [`pty`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/pty.html) module. It may also work on other *nix platforms, but it may not—even if it gets built and included in your stdlib. As the docs say:

> Because pseudo-terminal handling is highly platform dependent, there is code to do it only for Linux. (The Linux code is supposed to work on other platforms, but hasn’t been tested yet.)

It definitely runs on *BSD platforms on 2.7 and 3.3, and the example in the docs seem to work on both Mac OS X and FreeBSD… but that's as far as I've checked.

---

Meanwhile, most POSIX platforms will at least have [`os.forkpty`](http://docs.python.org/3.3/library/os.html#os.forkpty), and that's not much harder, so here's a trivial program that plays the first 5 seconds of a song passed as its first arg:

```
import os
import pty
import sys
import time

pid, fd = os.forkpty()
if pid:
    time.sleep(5)
    os.write(fd, 'q')
else:
    os.spawnl(os.P_WAIT, # mode
              '/usr/local/bin/mpg123', # path
              '/usr/local/bin/mpg123', '-C', sys.argv[1]) # args
```

---

Note that I used `os.spawnl` above. This is probably *not* what you want in a real program; it's for pedagogic purposes, to encourage you to read the docs (and the corresponding manpages) and understand this family of functions.

As [the docs](http://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.spawnl) explain, this does not use the `PATH` environment variable, so you need to specify the full path to the program. You can just use `spawnlp` instead of `spawnl` to fix this.

Also, `spawn` may (in fact, always does, although the docs aren't entirely clear) do another fork to execute the child. This really isn't necessary, but `spawn` does things that you would need to do manually if you just called `exec`. If you know what you're doing, you may well want to use `execl` (or `execlp`) instead of `spawnl`.

You can even use most of the functionality in `subprocess` as long as you're careful (do not create any pipes, and remember that you'll end up doing *two* `fork`s, so make sure to set up the parent/child relationship properly).

Also notice that you need to pass the path to `mpg123` *twice*—once as the path, and then once as the child program's `argv[0]`. You could also just pass `mpg123` the second time. Or, ideally, look at what `ps` says when you run it from the shell, and pass that. At any rate, you have to pass *something* as the `argv[0]`; otherwise, `-C` ends up being the `argv[0]`, which means mpg123 won't think you gave it a `-C` flag to enable control keys, but rather than you renamed it to `-C` and ran it with no flags…

Anyway, you really do need to read the docs to understand what each of these functions does, instead of just treating it like magic code that you don't understand. So, I intentionally used the simplest possible solution to encourage that.

---

On Windows, there is no such thing as a `pty`, and no way to do this at all with the facilities built in to Python. You will need to use one of the various third-party libraries for controlling a cmd.exe console (aka DOS prompt) instead.

Comment: this looks very promising;thank you ^_^ unfortunately it's whole new territory for me, so I got to go read documentation and see if I can find tutorials ^_^

Comment: I couldn't get the example code to work at first, with a slight modification though... instead of '/usr/local/bin/mpg123' mine was located just in '/usr/bin/mpg123'. Time to tinker, thank you again ^_^

Comment: @newbToPython: I was assuming you knew where you'd installed `mpg123`. But that raises a good point: with `subprocess` you don't really have to worry about the `PATH`; with the `os.spawn*` variants, you have to read the docs and think about it. Let me update the answer to explain.

Comment: I'm also a newbToLinux lol, though I am going to edit my original post with the updated changes as I seem to have come across another issue using pty

Comment: ok, thanks a lot to your help (a TON of reading in the documentation), and a whole bunch of time, I have a working prototype ^_^ Your change to the os.spawn got me thinking about the arguments used, I'm actually using a list instead of sys.argv[1], so I've changed the last argument to *playList so I can add multiple files to mpg123's playlist from a known set of audio files in the script. I very much appreciate all of your help, you've been patient and wonderful, so thank you ^_^

Answer (score 1):

Based on abarnert's idea, we can open a pseudo-terminal and pass it to subprocess.

```
import os
import pty
import subprocess
import time

master, slave = os.openpty()

p = subprocess.Popen(['mpg123', '-C', 'music.mp3'], stdin=master)
time.sleep(3)
os.write(slave, 's')
time.sleep(3)
os.write(slave, 's')
time.sleep(6)
os.write(slave, 'q')
```